# UR3 RT remote position control

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're looking for a simple way to control the position of the head (end effector/ TCP) of a UR3e robot.

The requirements are simple, we wish to send in real time 6DOF representing the head position in the world - p[x,y,z,ax,ay,az], and have the robot move the in a simple linear manner.
Manual calibration of the pose is possible.

The goal is to close a loop with an external operator (teleoperation), for example an "absolute" joystick.
The closest references found:

- Move Group for generating poses
- Jog control as refereto connecting to UR3 - https://github.com/tork-a/jog_control

Any thought would be appreciated.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344966/ur3-rt-remote-position-control/) by [SometimesButMaybe](https://answers.ros.org/users/45138/sometimesbutmaybe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-02-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest you take a look at the [wiki/ur_robot_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/ur_robot_driver) package. This would provide you with a driver capable of interfacing with the real-time external motion capabilities of the UR controller (at either 125 or 500 Hz, depending on which exact model of controller you have).

After starting the driver, switch to the [JointGroupVelocityController](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/d4e1e6a232d01ac7c165133dc58c874d66bfa7e4/ur_robot_driver/config/ur3_controllers.yaml#L139-L142) using the `controller_manager`'s services.

Then simply provide appropriate setpoints to the driver at the expected rate (ie: either 125 or 500 Hz) to close the loop.

You may want to take a look at the `jog_arm` package that was recently merged into MoveIt: [Arm Jogging in Real-Time](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/arm_jogging/arm_jogging_tutorial.html).

> The requirements are simple, we wish to send in real time 6DOF representing the head position in the world - p[x,y,z,ax,ay,az], and have the robot move the in a simple linear manner.

I like your repeated use of "simple". You are probably aware how "not simple" this sort of task is in a distributed control setting with (almost) infinite variation in input devices and (almost) infinite variation in system-to-be-controlled (the fact you use a UR3 specifically doesn't really matter, there can be no assumptions about this in the software).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SometimesButMaybe](https://answers.ros.org/users/45138/sometimesbutmaybe/) on 2020-02-25**:
Hi!
Thanks for the through answer, we'll definitely use the materials you sent.

You got a point about the "simple" terminology.. It comes from us expecting this functionality to be more integrated into the UR ecosystem (ROS aside), and learning the limitations as we progress through our project..